# Use of subjunctinve in a North & Hillard translation exercise

Tags: grammar-identification, conjunctive, english-to-latin-translation

North & Hillard Ex. 228 includes:

> Next day Caesar had again an army which, though diminished, was prepared to face all dangers manfully.

A footnote states: "Of the concessive conjunctions *quamvis* is most frequently used where the verb is omitted."
The Answer Book gives:

> *Postridie igitur Caeser exercitum habuit restitutum, qui, quamvis deminutus, pericula fortiter obire paratus est.*

If deploying *quamvis* why not use the subjunctive as the grammatical rule requires, giving *quamvis deminueretur*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do need a subjunctive, but here the pluperfect *diminutus esset* rather the imperfect that you propose provides the correct sequence of tenses. Just as the English omits the auxiliary verb, so has this been contracted (in a quite normal way) from 'though it had been diminished' to 'though diminished' by omitting *esset*.

Comment: +1 but, isn't also possible to read _diminutus_ working as an adjective? (And hence explain the reference to verb omission?)

Comment: @Rafael Just a matter of style. Without an auxiliary verb, it is effectively an adjective. Doesn't any participle, in effect, have all the properties of an adjective?

Comment: @Rafael I think verb omission here means the omission of a verb in a personal form, not a full omission. I would read *deminutus* as a participle belonging to the pluperfect with implicit *esset* as Tom did. (The analogy to English is a good observation here! The omission of auxiliary verbs is not unique to Latin.)